# Can Careers add patents and other credits?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

On my linkedin, I have sections for my patents and movie credits.

Any thought that those could be added to Careers?  Or perhaps I am just overlooking?

Comment: In the mean time, I think it would be a good idea to have a link somewhere to your LinkedIn.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As noted, this broader information appears on LinkedIn, whereas Careers is dev centric

> Sure, your employment history is *probably* impressive, but what about all that other stuff? Like the app you built during a 24 hour hackathon, or the question you answered on Stack Overflow that tripled your reputation overnight? **We built profiles with developers like you in mind**

[source, Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/why-stack)

The argument could be made that if you expand the remit of Careers to accommodate more non development based information, where is the line for what else should be included?

Careers then moves into becoming more like LinkedIn and diverges away from its specific, focused, raison d'etre.

This type of other information is naturally important (no argument there)- and helps flesh you out as a potential candidate, however it is likely best to link to your LinkedIn profile as opposed to Careers effectively attempting to replicate/accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not too special?

After movie credits, we may need

- bug reports
- bug fixes
- non-bug contributions
- translation credits (for when you helped translating something)
- voluntary work
- books
- customer websites
- newsletters and blogs (*)

These are just those which would apply to me (including the near future).

I mean, of course, I would welcome all those, but the plethora of other careerists each may have other specialties. And movie credits, for example, don't apply to the majority of users.

**Proposal:**
Custom sections. With suggestions for the most common things.

---

<sub>(*): Yes, I know, some of them are there already. But for example, I don't really like having bug-reports below open source projects.</sub>

Comment: This is normally a bad idea on a CV, mainly since if your CV is too long it will not be read. HR regularly only read about the 2 pages of a CV, and at a glance at that (since they have hundreds of other applicants) so filling up 5 pages with random sections and jibberish seems like a bad idea

Comment: @Sammaye: Surely. But this depends on the local conventions of the company you apply for. And you can jibberishify it now already. For someone applying for an OpenSource position, a bug-report/contribution section makes a lot of sense. For someone applying in the CG industry, like the OP, a movie credits section can make a lot of sense. Applying for university roles, thesises and papers are relevant.